# Error changes folder permissions

Tags: joomla, foreach, jomsocial

In using jomsocial 2.8.4 and Joomla 2.5.9 we tried uploading an image to his feed using the "multifunction" status box. Which then crashed the site. After investigating it turns out that my root folder /public_html/ permissions were changed to 777 when this error looped and changed permissions from 755 so by the security set in my cPanel, it threw the 500 error..once fixing the permission issue my site was back online but the status he was trying to upload the picture now displays.

The error from the error log before it crashes is:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/gamer/public_html/components/com_community/libraries/photos.php on line 11

Any fixes for this?

Comment: did you report this to jomsocial team? looks like a pretty nasty bug

Comment: JomSocial is a commercial extension and therefore would be best if you contact the developers ;)

Comment: Did report it to jomsocial, the answer was we will look into it. lol sure could use a fix for this at least once a day crashes @Riccardo Zorn

Answer (score 0):

OK so change the image your uploading to .png to see if its not loading because of extention, next how big is your image. this can also cause upload errors, also check to make your exec times are set up higher then 8mb do like 32mb you can change that in php.ini

Also you can uninstall jomsocial and reinstall it also check jomsocial settings in the backend under media to make sure those are set you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my own joomla component.

- It doesn't depend on image size. The same image file sometimes uploads properly, and sometimes changes permissions of the /public_html/ to 777.
- I've tried yet only jpg files.

It looks like it's Joomla bug, not Joomsocial.

**UPDATE:**
The problem is inside JFile::delete();

```
// somehow set 777 rights to the /public_html/ directory
JFile::delete(JPATH_SITE.$table->img_orig);

//solution
if (JFile::exists(JPATH_SITE.$table->img_orig))
  JFile::delete(JPATH_SITE.$table->img_orig);
```